# How to redirect an specific url with specific variables in iis

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect, url

The idea is to add a rule to my iis (version 7) to redirect this

> http://www.mydomain.com/folder/Default.aspx?&variable1=eeee&variable2=aaa

to:

> http://www.mydomain.com/folder/Default.aspx?&variable1=ffff&variable2=gggg

But it have to be only with this specific url and all the urls must mantain the same thing

I read this article http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx but is for patterns and all url and this is an specific url

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^folder/Default.aspx$" />
          <action 
              type="Redirect" 
              url="folder/Default.aspx?&amp;variable1=ffff&amp;variable2=gggg" 
              appendQueryString="false" 
              redirectType="Found" /> 

          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" 
                 pattern="^&amp;variable1=eeee&amp;variable2=aaa$" />

            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" 
                 pattern="^variable1=eeee&amp;variable2=aaa$" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Set the `redirectType` attribute in the `<action>` element to one of:

- `Permanent` for a `301 Permanent` redirect
- `Found` for a `302 Found` redirect

This covers the possibility of the query string being:

`&variable1=eeee&variable2=aaa`  - as per your example, with a leading ampersand

or with the leading ampersand:

`variable1=eeee&variable2=aaa`

If you just want a straight rewrite without doing a redirect then change the `<action>` element to:

```
<action type="Rewrite" 
        url="folder/Default.aspx?&amp;variable1=ffff&amp;variable2=gggg" 
        appendQueryString="false" />
```

Comment: Hi Kev, it worked great!, can I ask you one more favor? I have a problem with some special characters on one of the urls:
http://domain.com/login.aspx?TargetURL=%2fxxx%2fDefault.aspx%3f%26RoomID%3dyyy%26GameID%3dxxx&RoomID=yyy&GameID=xxx

Comment: @Saikios - glad it worked. Just ask a new question on the site.

Comment: done @kev http://serverfault.com/questions/387323/probelm-with-encoding-on-web-config

Comment: If your IIS web site's root isn't an ASP.Net application, do you need to stick the rewrite rules in machine.config?