# How to deal with certain characters in IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite, encoding

I had a question on how to rewrite a url and had a great answer on the site, and it worked, but there is some characters that I can't find how to encode and iis doesn't like at all

The original question was this:

> [How to redirect an specific url with specific variables in iis](https://serverfault.com/questions/386573/how-to-redirect-an-specific-url-with-specific-variables-in-iis/386897#comment399833_386897)

The character in questions are:

> ```
> http://www.domain.com/login.aspx?TargetURL=%2fxxx%2fDefault.aspx%3f%26RoomID%3dyyy%26GameID%3dxxx&RoomID=yyy&GameID=xxx`
> ```

I tried almost everything on the net to fix this, but some of the characters like `=` and `/` just don't work. I know for example that replacing & with `&amp;` works, but the others are the real problem.